# How to troubleshoot a connection timeout error

Tags: networking, blocking, timeout

I'm from Colorado and living in Hong Kong, so I occasionally need to do business on the state government website, colorado.gov.  I noticed several years ago that I've had problems reaching the site, despite downforeveryoneorjustme.com reporting no problems and no issues mentioned in the news or other forums.

Initially, I would get DNS errors (that the domain was not recognized), but those stopped when I switched to Google's public DNS servers.  Now, if I try to reach the site (on Chrome 53.0.2785.143 m, Windows 10) I always get a ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT error.

In the past, I've been able to download files from the site by getting a copy of the page I need from Google Cache, but now I need to upload something.  What's the next step in trying to fix this problem?  Is my only option a VPN/remote desktop?

Answer (score 0):

The [website availability tools at site24x7.com](https://www.site24x7.com/check-website-availability.html) helped me determine that the site was blocked in all of China.  I was able to have someone back in the US submit a help request with the website admin and reach me by email.